# listbox values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two list boxes. I am able to add values to one listbox through a textbox. From this listbox i add the desired values to listbox2 by clicking the add button.

Now i am not able to get how to add the values from the second listbox to a database table called Machines. these values get added to different rows.

```
Listbox2

PC1 

PC2

PC3
```

and add these to database table Machines

Please help me out

This is the code for passing values from one listbox to other...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ArrayList lasset = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList lsubordinate = new ArrayList();
        static ArrayList UpdateList = new ArrayList();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //add one by one//
        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        if (!lasset.Contains(ListBox1.Items[i]))
                        {
                            lasset.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < lasset.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)lasset[i])))
                    {
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(((ListItem)lasset[i]));
                    }
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(((ListItem)lasset[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        //Add all
        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (ListBox1.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!lasset.Contains(ListBox1.Items[i]))
                    {
                        lasset.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < lasset.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)lasset[i])))
                    {
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(((ListItem)lasset[i]));
                    }
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(((ListItem)lasset[i]));
                }
            }
                    }
        //remove from listbox2 and add to listbox1//
        protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBox2.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        if (!lsubordinate.Contains(ListBox2.Items[i]))
                        {
                            lsubordinate.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < lsubordinate.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i])))
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i]));
                    }
                    ListBox2.Items.Remove(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i]));
                    UpdateList.Add(lsubordinate[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        //remove all
        protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (ListBox2.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!lsubordinate.Contains(ListBox2.Items[i]))
                    {
                        lsubordinate.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < lsubordinate.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i])))
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i]));
                    }
                    ListBox2.Items.Remove(((ListItem)lsubordinate[i]));
                    UpdateList.Add(lsubordinate[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to give us a little bit more information about the type of database you are using.

Comment: It would really help if you could tell us what kind of database you were using.

Comment: What's your question exactly ? I don't see any data access code in your snippet... Did you even try ?

Comment: i am using SQl database...
Even a example to add the values in database from a listview will help
thanks

Comment: myConn.Open();
OleDbCommand dataCommand = new OleDbCommand();

        if (ListBox2.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem i in ListBox2.Items)
            {
                insertContractCmd = ("insert into table column1) values ('" + ListBox2.Items + "')", myConn);

            }
        }

        myConn.Open();
        dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

Comment: Please give your controls and variables better names :(

Answer (score 1):

You supplied this code in your comment.

```
myConn.Open();
OleDbCommand dataCommand = new OleDbCommand();
if (ListBox2.Items.Count > 0) {
    foreach (ListItem i in ListBox2.Items) {
        insertContractCmd = ("insert into table column1) values ('"
                            + ListBox2.Items
                            + "')", myConn);
        }
    }
    myConn.Open();
    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I see three problems with the code:

First, a parenthesis mismatch in the insert command. Change `("insert into table column1)` to `"insert into table (column1)`

Second, you open the connection twice. Lose the second `myConn.Open();`

Third, and this is the biggest problem - you are trying to concatenate a string with the entire list of items. What you should do is concatenate each item separately, like this:

```
// note: this is a bad example, use the next one instead
insertContractCmd = "insert into table (column1) values (";
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items) {
    insertContractCmd = insertContractCmd + "'" + item.Text + "'";
}
insertContractCmd = insertContractCmd + ")";
```

Now you only have to deal with one small problem - this code is bad because it causes a lot of string concatenation which is inefficient and consumes a lot of memory. You should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead:

```
StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder("insert into table (column1) values (");
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items) {
    commandBuilder.AppendFormat("'{0}'", item.Text);
}
commandBuilder.Append(")");
insertContractCmd = commandBuilder.ToString();
```

Note: I also used AppendFormat for the same efficiency reasons. You could also use `commandBuilder.Append("'" + item.Text + "'");` to the same effect.

Hope that helps, `configurator`.

Comment: this is great...
But i have another problem... I have a dropdownlist which has come values in it. 
I need to write a query which takes the value from this dropdownlist, gets the ID value from that value and put those values in the table with that ID value.

I know its too much, but it will be great if you could help in some way. thanks